# How to save an image using CircleImageView Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I wrote a program where a user can click a TextView (editPhoto) and select an image (profile picture) and display on the profile and also save it on my database with the rest of the profile details, but as soon as I leave the page the picture disappears from the CircleImageView although it's still saved on my database. I am able to save the rest of the users information on the profile like name, username, email etc using .setText() so how can I do the same with the CircleImageView for the profile picture? Thanks in advance

**CODE:**

```
 private TextView editPhoto;
 CircleImageView profilePic;
 
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

        profilePic = findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
        editPhoto = findViewById(R.id.txtEditPP);
       
        editPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chooseFile();
            }
        });
    }

 private void chooseFile(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Photo"),1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){
            Uri filepath = data.getData();

            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filepath);
                profilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            UploadPicture(getId, getStringImage(bitmap));
        }
    }

    //UPLOAD PROFILE PICTURE
    private void UploadPicture(final String id, final String photo) {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_UPLOAD, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i(TAG, response.toString());

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                    String success = jsonObject.getString("success");

                    if (success.equals("1")){
                        Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, "Photo Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, "Error Uploading Image!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this, "Error Uploading Image!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("ID", id);
                params.put("photo", photo);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bitmap){
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);

        byte[] imageByteArr = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageByteArr, Base64.DEFAULT);

        return encodedImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In onResume can you reload imageView using bitmap object?
Also make bitmap object as class variable reloading image will work for you in this case.